# How to prevent having a thorn in your side when you can't delete your old question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, vote-to-delete

I'm a low rep user, but active mostly on SE. I'm still working on it (can see that from recent question and answer), but I believe I now understand how to be decent when both asking and answering questions.

However, what about the "thorn"? In this case, this would be this:
[Python - Case where Print works but Return doesn't in a basic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65757821/python-case-where-print-work-but-return-doesnt-in-a-basic-function)

This is one of the first Python related question I asked, when I didn't know better (I am not an expert, but now I feel like I know what I'm doing, compared to before at least).

The problem is that it keeps being downvoted (for good reason too, as mentioned), but now that it:

1. has an answer
2. I corrected the error of my ways (I think)

How do I fix this if I cannot prevent getting downvoted for a bad question like this? Especially because I do not think I could fix it to be "good" at this point, nor can I delete it because of how SO works (it prevents you from doing so when there is an accepted answer, etc...)

Does that mean I'm doomed to have people downvote me for an old bad question forever?

Comment: will that really prevent the future downvote from going to me? just for that question right? @MartinSmith I read the post and answer but want to make sure

Comment: As far as I know the post is anonymised and has no linkage with your account.

Comment: Though I'm *not* suggesting you do the following if you think the answer is helpful, that question *is* deletable if you remove the accepted mark for the answer first. As for acquiring downvotes, you got *one* today, *one* on October 21, and then any prior were *way back* in 2021; it's really not getting that many considering its age. Your actions here are more likely to invoke the meta effect compared to if you had ignored it.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions

Comment: and also here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: I tried doing that before asking, but that didn't work. Also, I do think this question isn't worth anything in terms of knowledge/helpfulness, so I think it's fine to delete it. @Larnu

Comment: Thank you, Martin and Thingamabobs. Think I got it now :)

Comment: @Larnu the answer has an upvote and according to the SE Q&A -- *has an answer with upvotes (even if that answer has a net zero or negative score)* -- is not delete-able

Comment: Didn't notice the upvote, nice catch, @Thingamabobs .

Comment: Everyone gets downvotes, particularly on old stuff one posted as a new user. The best way might be to simply endure and post better posts to weigh out the bad ones. If you are to make some disassociation request every time someone down votes one of your posts, that's just going to be very frustrating in the long run.

Comment: @Larnu regarding the Meta effect: Yes, I was aware this was a possibility before I asked too, but the thing is, I'm a low-rep user. My main concern isn't so much the reputation, but what they entail (eg: being able to have enough in the future to talk in chat, etc). If I keep getting them because of those "thorns", then it would be fruitless.

Comment: I agree, and I did think of doing that (you can notice this by looking at the recent activity anyway) but it's a time-sensitive and personal work-related activity. I want to pour my soul and being into the answer I give, so that it may help someone *and* not impact my reputation over the long run. recently, I even found myself noticing ways to answer an unanswered question I find on SO, but put it off for later and slowly but surely writing a good answer for it, based on my own "research". While this is time-sensitive, I will still receive downvotes on those "thorns", while I do that. @Lundin

Comment: I disassociated 3 questions I posted years ago (1 was deleted IIRC). They were gone in 2 hours. I went to https://meta.stackexchange.com, then *Contact*, chose *Other* from the dropdown and explained in a few words which questions I wanted to disassociate and why.

Comment: I suppose you could also try to get the whole thing deleted, if you can rally 3 high rep Python users (in the Python chat?) and have them cast delete votes. This under the assumption that the answer is of no value. Disassociation won't delete bad or useless content from the site.

Comment: "I want to pour my soul and being into the answer I give..."; You might want to re-evaluate your level of emotional involvement here.

Comment: I never said I had any emotional attachment whatsoever to this place. I only meant that I don't like doing something that would make me self-doubt or "guilty" of giving subpar answers/questions. This may look emotional, but I view it as being my own "work" (not the right word I know) ethic. I respect anyone else who doesn't do the same, however. @MarkBenningfield

Comment: No need to put it in terms often associated with emotion then. If there is one way people shoot themselves in the foot on this site it is by using wrong terminology which causes confusion and hip firing. You don't want to make mistakes you can avoid. Simple as that, right? A lofty goal, it should involve spending a large amount of time consuming the existing content on meta. The first time I learned meta existed, I just dropped what I was doing and spent 5 days reading. Afterwards I had but one thing to say for myself: "whoops".

Comment: I don't think those terms are always associated with emotions, but I get what you mean. It depends on context though, so I'm sure there are other ways to interpret them. Also, I agree it's important to use the "right" terminology, but I was literally speaking about myself here. How can I know the right terminology to use when you talk about something specific about yourself, that ***everyone*** can agree on? I can't, so I use the closest one that fit the current context. if I ever make an error of judgment, I'll correct myself of course, but I don't think I used the incorrect terms here.@Gimby

Comment: If it's any consolation - I don't think that was a bad question - it's one everyone can fall into when first starting out. You can request disassociation as mentioned earlier in comments but it's really not doing you any harm account wise and is a useful sign post for others as well. I'd be tempted to try and not worry about it and chalk it up to experience.

Comment: Can agree, it took me a while till I got to `yield`, even if it is not mentioned in the accepted answer but the duplicate. So it is useful to driving a point home.

Comment: @JonClements: Well now that it's up to positive votes it won't be a thorn in his side either.

Comment: A bit late but, before I forget: Thanks to everyone's advice and reality checks. I think this makes things clearer for me :)